# Unable to install rbenv with deployer user in CentOS - Permission denied

Tags: centos, deployment

I created a new user in CentOS 6.3 using this commands

```
useradd deployer

passwd deployer

visudo
```

then I added this line to file:

```
deployer ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

Fine!

Now I trying to install rbenv, to deploy an RoR application. I followed this steps:

```
cd /home/deployer

su deployer

curl https://raw.github.com/fesplugas/rbenv-installer/master/bin/rbenv-installer | bash
```

It worked. After, I added rbenv to .bashrc and tried to reload .bashrc file and
get this error:

```
[deployer@mycentos ~]$ . ~/.bashrc 
bash: /home/deployer/.rbenv/bin/rbenv: Permission denied
```

Anyone know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved!**

I was getting this error because `/home` folder was mounted with `noexec` option.

```
$cat /etc/fstab 
...
/dev/mapper/VG00-LVhome /home  ext4    defaults,noexec,nosuid        1 2
```

Now, I changed app to `/usr` folder and it works!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're not getting your environment set correctly when you do `su deployer`.  Try `sudo -iu deployer`, so that you get the environment of that user as well.